# NSPredicate Core Data

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, nspredicate

What is the exact difference between `LIKE [c]%@` and `= [c]%@` in core data `NSPredicate`? I want to search for a string that should exactly match the receiver.
Example :

```
NSArray *arrayNames = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:NSStringFromClass([PatientFamilyMember class])
      withSortColumn:nil withSortDescending:FALSE
      withPredicate:@"patientID = %@ && firstName=[c]%@ && relationship=[c]%@ && lastName=[c]%@",
      self.pfm.patientID, firstName, relationship, lastName];
```

This works but I have not understood the difference between using `LIKE [c]` and `= [c]%@.`

Answer (score 14):

The difference between `LIKE` and `=` in a predicate is that `LIKE` allows `?` and `*` as wildcard characters, where `?` matches 1 character and `*` matches 0 or more characters.

Both `LIKE` and `=` can be modified with `[c]` to specify case insensitivity.

Example: Assume that you have objects with names

```
"Mark", "mark", "Mike", "mike", "M*"
```

Both

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", @"Mark"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE %@", @"Mark"];
```

find "Mark", and both

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name =[c] %@", @"Mark"];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE[c] %@", @"Mark"];
```

find "Mark" and "mark". But only the `LIKE` operator can be used with wildcards, e.g.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE[c] %@", @"M*"];
```

finds "Mark", "mark", "Mike", "mike" and "M*", but

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name ==[c] %@", @"M*"];
```

finds only "M*".

See [String Comparisons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) in the "Predicate Programming Guide" for more information.

Comment: An excellent and clear answer.  I wish you worked in Apple's documentation department...