# How can I use an NSPredicate to select an exact phrase from an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, nspredicate

I am using an NSPredicate to filter an NSDictionary by a list of states and countries.

All the data are stored in a comma separated array: @"Alabama", @"Alaska", @"Arizona", @"Arkansas", @"California", @"Colorado", etc

However, there are 2 situations where duplicates are occurring. The state "New Mexico" contain the word "Mexico", and "Arkansas" contains the word "Kansas.

Here's the basic code I'm using to define the predicate.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location contains[c] %@", @"Kansas"];
```

How can I make sure "Kansas" doesn't return objects with "Arkansas"?
Using BEGINSWITH or LIKE doesn't work because the list begins with some other state.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `@"Location == %@"` ?

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to be the same as using BEGINSWITH or LIKE. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: What do you mean by "the list begins with some other state"? operators == or LIKE should select the exact phrase...

Comment: @Jonah: `==` is for exact comparison and does not the same as BEGINSWITH or LIKE. Perhaps you can add a concrete example where `==` does not work as expected. It is also unclear to me where the "Location" property comes from if you have just an array of strings. For the difference between "==" and LIKE, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578513/nspredicate-core-data/14579164#14579164.

Comment: I tried:    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location == %@", @"Kansas"]; and it returned no results.

Comment: "Location" is a value in an NSDictionary that contains the states each item is found in. So "Location" could contain "Alabama, Mississippi, New Mexico"

Comment: Could you post the code where you fill up the array please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see if I understand correctly. You have a dictionary, where there is a key "Location" whose object is a string with comma separated state names. Sounds like you need a regular expression to match.

```
NSString* expr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^%1$@.*|.*, %1$@.*", @"Kansas"]  
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location MATCHES[c] %@", expr];
```

Now, here is how it would behave for different examples:

```
@{@"Location": @"Kansas, Arkansas, Alabama"} //Pass
@{@"Location": @"Alabama, Kansas"} //Pass
@{@"Location": @"Arkansas, Alabama"} //Fail
```

---

The regular expression `^%1$@.*|.*, %1$@.*` tests if the word provided is either at the start of the string or followed by characters and ", ", which puts it in the middle. `%1$@` takes the first param, so that it can be used multiple times instead of prividing the same string several times.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening when you are creating the string with this?  @"^%1$@.*|.*, %1$@.*"

Comment: I'm guessing you're saying that "Kansas" is either the first object, or it is preceded by a ", "   Is that about right?

Comment: That's exactly what it says, actually.

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps?

```
// If I understood correctly, then your locations in the dictionary are like this
NSString *locations = @"Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas";

NSString *trimmedLocations = [locations stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *compoments = [[trimmedLocations componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];   
//now in components we have this: @[@"Alabama", @"Alaska", @"Arizona", @"Arkansas", @"California", @"Colorado"]

[compoments filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isEqualToString:@"Kansas"];
}]];

BOOL match = compoments.count;
if (match) {
    //do something with locations...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location IN %@", myStatesArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an exact match predicate search:

> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location == [c] %@", @"Kansas"];

Am I understanding your question incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

It will work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name LIKE[c] %@", myString];
```

LIKE matches strings with ? and * as wildcards. The [c] indicates that the comparison should be case insensitive.

If you don't want ? and * to be treated as wildcards, you can use == instead of LIKE:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name ==[c] %@", myString];
```

More info in the NSPredicate Predicate Format String Syntax [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB).

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location matches[c] %@", @"Kansas"];
```

This must help you with the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try your `predicate` with `matches` keyword, it will give you the exact result match and accordingly you can remove the duplicate occurence in the predicate as below-

```
NSArray *yourArr=@[@"Alabama", @"Alaska", @"Arizona", @"Arkansas", @"California", @"Colorado"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Location contains[CD] %@", @"Kansas"];
NSMutableArray *filterdArray=[yourArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if(filterdArray.count>0)
{
NSLog(@"Invalid State");
 }
```